# OpenAI: What is the difference between model "gpt-3.5-turbo" and "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301"?

Tags: open-ai, chatgpt, large-language-models

I have performed an API call to OpenAI's endpoint https://api.openai.com/v1/models .

The endpoint lists the currently available engines, and provides basic information about each one such as the owner and availability.

As a logged-in user, I get a JSON response of 63 models. These are the most recent ones (currently) , formatted, shown with release date.

```
59: "11/28/2022, 2:40:35 AM : text-davinci-003"
60: "12/16/2022, 8:01:39 PM : text-embedding-ada-002"
61: "2/27/2023, 10:13:04 PM : whisper-1"
62: "2/28/2023,  7:56:42 PM : gpt-3.5-turbo"
63: "3/1/2023,   6:52:43 AM : gpt-3.5-turbo-0301"
```

I notice that there are 2 very similar models , "gpt-3.5-turbo" and "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301", with `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` released only 11 hours after `gpt-3.5-turbo`.

What is the difference between these two model versions? It does not seem to be a glitch or a misnaming error. Why did OpenAI bother to include both of them, and why didn't take the inferior version?

(I haven't experimented with these two models in any way yet. I might do this very soon. However I though I might as well ask here. Informing others in this forum might have some benefit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5

[image]

I think its literally an update but the specifics of what that updates are I do not know I looked through the documentation but this was all I could find.

Comment: Thanks. I think the decisive keyword from the documentation you posted is "snapshot". I think OpenAI received some outrage recently, when they announced their intention to remove the previous iteration,  because many 3rd-party researchers and reviewers would have lost their "baseline model" which they refer to in their manuscripts pending review and publication.

Comment: Ah interesting, I did not know that, thanks for the info. It is very hard to keep up with AI at the moment. I wanted to answer your question as soon as I seen it because I am trying myself to understand the docs at the moment haha.